# how to compare strings in c

Tags: c, string

I have the next strange situation:

```
void refill (Car* car) {
    if ( car->model == "BM234" ) {
        car->fuel = 65;
    } else {
        car->fuel = 51;
    }
}
```

My struct Car has af field called model and it is "BM234". But the result of the comparison is car->fuel = 51((( Why two equal strings for C are not equal?

Comment: What is the type of car->model?

Comment: There is a search option in StackOverflow, please use it as a such common question has been asked many times.

Comment: The type of car->model is char model[100]. I used the search option ans saw about strcmp. But my question here is why my logic is wrong. I want to undestand it.

Comment: Your logic is only "wrong" in the sense that C **does not allow** this notation to compare strings. It's the same for other 'logical' operations. In Python, for example, you can 'add' and 'multiply' strings: `x = 5*"hello"`, which do exactly what one *logically* would expect. Alas, there is a vast difference between 'logically' and 'what the language allows'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
strcmp( car->model,"BM234")==0
```

If you want to use == you must using `operator overloading` for your class or struct

Answer (score 0):

`if ( car->model == "BM234" ) {`

this is not way to compare string in `C`. `==` is used for compare single character.

use [strcmp](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strcmp.html) to compare string in `C`.

Answer (score 0):

The == operator in C compares pointers. So if you have two different pointers, both pointing to the strings with the exact same characters, the result will be 0 or false.

To compare strings use strcmp. strcmp returns 0 if both strings are equal, a negative number if the first string should be sorted before the second one, and a positive number if the first string should be sorted after the second one. So you would write

```
if (strcmp (car->model, "BM234") == 0) ...
```